# Android timer with RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, observable

I want to implement simple timer, which will counting values from 1 to 30 every second. When it reach 30 i want it to stop. Now i have something like this, but i don't know how to stop it after 30 seconds.

Here's the code:

```
Observable<Long> observable = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    observable.subscribe(
            new Action1<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Long aLong) {
                    Log.d("Observable timer: ", aLong.toString());
                }
            },
            new Action1<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Throwable error) {
                    System.out.println("Error encountered: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            },
            new Action0() {
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    System.out.println("Sequence complete");
                }
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 15):

Do you want to count once?

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.take(30) // up to 30 items
.map(v -> v + 1) // shift it to 1 .. 30
.subscribe(System.out::println);

Thread.sleep(35000);
```

Count repeatedly from 1 to 30?

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.map(v -> (v % 30) + 1) // shift it to 1 .. 30
.subscribe(System.out::println);

Thread.sleep(91000);
```

Comment: Cool, and how i can show this for example in a textView?

Comment: @wegtis `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(result -> textView.setText(result));`

Comment: @Dimezis it throws something like 'Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling'. How i can find solution for this?

Comment: @wegtis you need to add error handler as a second argument of subscribe method. Default error handler just rethrows an Exception, as it is in your case.

Comment: @Dimezis I've done something like this, but it doesn't work. Can you provide sample of fully working code?

Comment: @wegtis would be better if you provide your code sample and exact stack trace, because you are definitely doing something wrong - just adding `onError` handler works fine. Like I said `.subscribe(System.out::println, e -> handleError(e))`

Answer (score 15):

You can implement it like this:

```
public static final int TIMER_VALUE = 30;

....

Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnNext(new Consumer<Long>() {
                public void accept(Long x) throws Exception {
                    // update your view here
                    myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(x));
                }
            })
            .takeUntil(aLong -> aLong == TIMER_VALUE)
            .doOnComplete(() ->
                    // do whatever you need on complete
            ).subscribe()
```

Comment: There is no need to subscribeOn operator, as by default interval runs on Schedulers.computation thread...